# IFrame: How Do You Cut Off Content

Tags: html, iframe

I am trying to figure out, how to cut off the bottom content on an Iframe.

Example:

```
-------------------------------------
CONTENT
------------------------------------
BOTTOM
-------------------------------------
```

I want that to turn into:

```
-----------------------------------
CONTENT
------------------------------------
```

Comment: Tried changing the height and overflow?

Comment: Yeah, it just re sizes the Iframe and includes the Bottom Content